# Creating joomla article

Tags: joomla

I have question about creating article in joomla.
I created new article then the content of article was copy paste from word document.
My problem is the preview of the content in the website was not properly done and the
content was over the limit. The last some words was not been seen because of overlapped.

See the image what i said
Help me guys.. =(

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/571/88810506.jpg/

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste from word is always a nightmare. Before pasting you should clean the content. A simple way is paste into notepad and then copy from notepad and paste into the joomla editor.

If you use JCE (or JCK, as I don't remember) as your joomla editor there's a specific button to paste from word which will clean up the extra markup which word introduces.

Finally you may use any of the word cleaning online services ([check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67964/what-is-the-best-free-way-to-clean-up-word-html)).

Regards,